# Show email id field on selecting a particular dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Under Label responsibility select box if i choose others then i have to get an email id input box otherwise it should be hidden. But the email id field under the div i.e showMe, is showing on selecting Individual as well as others but not supervisors. I want it show only for others.I have Tried many combinations but I have no clue why this may not be working . Any clue why this is not working?

My HTML code is:

```html
<!-- Main content -->
<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->

<!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
<style>
tr > td
{
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
#showMe{
    display:none;
}
</style>
<section class="content-header">
<h1>
Add a new checklist

</h1>
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<li><a href="<?php base_url(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">My Requests</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>exits/resignation_request">Resignation Requests</a></li>
<li class="active">Add Resignation Request</li>
</ol>
</section>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<!-- Thought Day-->
<div class="panel wrapper clearfix m-b-none">

<div class="panel-body">

<input type="hidden" id="page_name" value="requests">

<?php if($error_message!=''){?>
<div class="success-message <?php echo $msg_class;?>"><?php echo $error_message;?>  </div>
<?php }  else { ?>
<?php  $row = $rows[0] ;
if(isset($row['grievance_type'])) {
$grievancetype = $row['grievance_type'];
} else { $grievancetype = ''; }

?>

<!-- form start -->
<?php echo form_open('exits/my_resignation_request/'.$id,array('name'=>'addostcstevent','id'=>'addostcstevent','method'=>'post','autocomplete'=>'on','class'=>'form-horizontal'))?>
<?php echo form_hidden(array('id'=>$row->id,'action'=>$action));?>
<div class="box-body">

<input type="hidden" name="todays_date" readonly id="todays_date" value="<?php echo date('m/d/y');?>" class="form-control col-md-10" <?php if($USER->permissions[0] != 'all') { ?> readonly <?php } ?>>




<table>
<tr>
<td>
Action Item
</td>
<td>

<input placeholder="Action Item" class=" m-wrap col-md-8 form-control " id="action" type="text" name="action" value="" required/>


</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Category
</td>
<td>

<select class="default" id="category" name="category">
        <option name="exit_type" value="" selected>Select a option</option>
  <option name="exit_type" value="Managers">Managers</option>
        <option name="exit_type" value="Admins">Admins</option>
        <option name="exit_type" value="Employees">Employees</option>
</select>




</td>
</tr>


<tr></tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label>Responsibility</label>
</td>
<td>
<select class="default" id="security_question" name="exit_type">
        <option name="exit_type" value="" selected>Select a option</option>
  
  <option name="exit_type" value="Individual">Individual</option>
        <option name="exit_type" value="Supervisors">Supervisors</option>
  <option name="exit_type" value="others">others</option>
    
</select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<label>Timelines for completion</label>
</td>
<td>
<div class="date" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" data-date-viewmode="years">
<input placeholder="Last working day" class=" m-wrap col-md-8 form-control " id="startdt" type="text" name="requested_date" value="<?php if($row->requested_date!='') echo date("d-m-Y",$row->requested_date); ?>" required/>
</td>
</tr>



</table>
<div id="showMe">
<table>

<tr>
<td>
Email ID
</td>
<td>
<input placeholder="Email" class=" m-wrap col-md-8 form-control " id="email" type="text" name="email" value="" required/>
  </td>
  </tr>
  
 </table> 
</div> 


</div><!-- /.box-body -->
<div class="box-footer">
<?php

echo form_hidden('action',$action);
echo form_hidden('id',$id);
?>
<!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" name="withdraw" style="margin:0px 10px" value="withdrawn">Withdraw Resignation</button>-->
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" style="margin:0px 10px">Submit</button>
</div><!-- /.box-footer -->
</form>
<?php } ?>
</div><!-- /.box -->
</div><!--/.col (right) -->
</div>   <!-- /.row -->
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="myLTAModal">

<div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Alert!</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<!-- modal content-->
<div class="panel-body">
<p>Ensure you refer to LTA guidelines before planning your trip. You will be required to submit your tickets as proof to avail LTA.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- modal content-->
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="leaveAllowedModal">

<div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Alert!</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<!-- modal content-->
<div class="panel-body">
<p class="allowed_text"></p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- modal content-->
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section><!-- /.content -->



<script>
/*$(document).ready(function(){
$('#reservation').daterangepicker();
})*/
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


<script>
var elem = document.getElementById("security_question");

elem.onchange = function(){
    var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById("showMe");
    hiddenDiv.style.display = (this.value == "Individual") ? "none":"none";
    hiddenDiv.style.display = (this.value == "Supervisors") ? "none":"block";
       hiddenDiv.style.hidden = (this.value == "others") ? "none":"none";

};

function parseDate(str) {
var mdy = str.split('/')
return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[0]-1, mdy[1]);
}

function daydiff(first, second) {
return Math.round((second-first)/(1000*60*60*24));
}
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#startdt").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
showButtonPanel: true,
yearRange: "-90:+0",
startDate: new Date(),
autoclose: true
}).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
$('#enddt').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
});
$("#enddt").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
showButtonPanel: true,
yearRange: "-90:+0"
});
$("#enddt").change(function(){
if($("#startdt").val()!='' && $("#enddt").val()!='')
{
var startdt = $("#startdt").val();
var enddt = $("#enddt").val();
$("#daysleave").val(daydiff(parseDate(startdt), parseDate(enddt)));
if($("#grievance_type").val()!='0')
{

var day_diff_today = daydiff(parseDate($("#today_dt").val()), parseDate($("#startdt").val()));

if(((parseInt($("#daysleave").val()) > parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-min"))) &&  (parseInt($("#daysleave").val()) < parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-max"))))&&(day_diff_today > parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-approvaldays"))))
{ } else {
$("#leaveAllowedModal").modal("show");
}

}
}
})
$("#grievance_type").change(function(){
if($("#startdt").val()!='' && $("#enddt").val()!='' && $("#grievance_type").val()!='0')
{
var day_diff_today = daydiff(parseDate($("#today_dt").val()), parseDate($("#startdt").val()));

if(((parseInt($("#daysleave").val()) > parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-min"))) &&  (parseInt($("#daysleave").val()) < parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-max"))))&&(day_diff_today > parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-approvaldays"))))
{ } else {
$("#leaveAllowedModal").modal("show");
}
}
})
$(".date-picker").datepicker();
$("#optionsRadios1").click(function(){
$("#myLTAModal").modal("show");
})
$('#leaveAllowedModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
var msg = '';
if((parseInt($("#daysleave").val()) > parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-min"))) &&  (parseInt($("#daysleave").val()) < parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-max"))))
{ } else {
msg = msg + "You wish you apply "+$("#daysleave").val()+" day of "+$("#grievance_type option:selected").text()+". Minimum and Maximum no. of Leaves allowed to take at a time are "+$("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-min")+" and "+$("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-max")+" respectively.";
}
var day_diff_today = daydiff(parseDate($("#today_dt").val()), parseDate($("#startdt").val()));
if((day_diff_today < parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-approvaldays"))))
{
msg = msg + " No. of days of prior approval needed is  " + $("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-approvaldays") + " days";
}
$(".allowed_text").html(msg);

})
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not use to write the code for every data element. Just use the below one.

Javascript :
    hiddenDiv.className  = ((this.value == "others") ? "showDiv":"hideDiv");

CSS :

```
.showDiv{
    display:block;
}
.hideDiv{
    display:none;
}
```

html : `<div id="showMe" class="hideDiv">`